# jQuery bind position:absolute to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i have a situation of:

```
<div class="hey1"><img class="img1"></img></div>
<div class="hey2"><img class="img2"></img></div>
<div class="hey3"><img class="img3"></img></div>
```

so .img imgaes are in position:absolute; binded to right top corner of related .hey div

when i fadeOut(); for example .hey1 div, the other .hey2,.hey3 divs scrolls more on top (right) but images binded remains on same absolute position, what i would like is to bind .img images also when fading out related div

any way to do that?

Comment: you want to fade both elements right?

Comment: elements are fading both (sorry) .. what i would like is when fading out while next divs moves more on top also related images scrolls with them :P

Comment: some kind of elements bind on the fly (dinamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your container divs have `position`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/D6Ucg/

In the example, click a yellow box to make it fade out. Then see what happens if you re-run the test after removing the `div { position: relative; }` style.

Comment: this is really good man... just main thing is that i would like to show images just outside of right-top div corner (like fancybox or other modals :P )

Comment: @ispuk, try using negative values for positioning, like `top: -10px; right: -10px;`. I [updated the example](http://jsfiddle.net/redler/D6Ucg/1/).

Comment: you are my hero!!!!!!! thanks , i would like to give you more then 1 point for answer but stack doesn't allows me :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of positioning `img` elements absolutely with in `div` elements, position them relatively. This way they will move along with the `div` when `div` is re-positioned through scroll or programmatically.